# What is the benefit of the reducers in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, reduce, reducers

I don't see a value for the reducers in Hadoop in the following scenario:

- The Map Tasks generate unique keys (Because we can merge both the Map/Reduce functionality together)
- The output size of the Map Tasks is too big (This will exhaust the memory if we wait for the reducers to begin the work)
- If we have any functionality that doesn't need grouping and sorting of the keys

Please correct me if I am wrong.

And if someone could give me a real example of the benefits of the reducers and when it should be used, I will appreciate it.

Comment: 3rd statement is central. If you don't need grouping, you should set number of reducers to 0.

Comment: @fi11er Thanks what about the first two statements

Comment: It all depends on your task, you can't do aggregating on mappers (or can, but you would probably write your own reduce for this). 1) if you have unique keys, you mostly don't need to group your data, so you don't need reducer. 2) it not depends on size, if you want to aggregate map output, you will add reducer.

Comment: @fi11er Thanks bro, but I noticed, when monitoring the tasks in Hadoop, that the reducers doesn't actually execute theirs tasks until the Mappers finish their tasks. This may exhaust the memory (container errors) if the mappers output are huge size like binary files. This is what I meant in the second statement. And It is real not suggesting or supposing. That's why I am asking what could be the solution. Is it to not use reducers or write our own reducers. And the point is if the reducer starts concurrently after a one mapper finishes there will be no problem but it waits till mappers finish.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer is beneficial (or required) when you need to do operations like aggregation/grouping etc..

FYI : Reducer is meant for grouping different value for a key which comes from different mapper. So for a use case which do not require grouping/aggregation then there is no point of using reducer(you can set it to Zero , meaning Map-Only jobs).

One quick use-case i can think of is - you want to randomly split a big file to multiple part file. In this case you will supply big file (lets say 100G) to Map-Only jobs. All maps will read a chunk of file and write as a part of file.

Comment: Thanks. what about the first two statements i.e. "The Map Tasks generate unique keys ......The output size of the Map Tasks is too big......" I think also here the Reducers should not be used. You provided an example of Map Only Jobs, Could you provide a "Real" example (i,e. live example not the concept) of the benefits of reducers, as I mentioned in my post.